# how to resolve AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, post, postman

I have created a database and I am trying to POST a "book" through Postman. The book should have a bunch of attributes such as title, author, rating, id, description etc. The database seems to work and I can, for example, get information about the logged in user through Postman.

When I try to POST a book I get the error as the headline; `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`  but I can't understand what 'list' the error is referring to..?
Here is the code for the route;

```
@app.route('/books', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def books():
    if Book.query.all() == None:
        abort(404)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Handle GET-request
        books = []
        for x in Book.query.all():
            books.append(Book.serialize(x))
        return jsonify(books)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        input_data = request.get_json(force=True)

        if not input_data.get('title', False):
            abort(400)
        if not input_data.get('author', False):
            abort(400)
        if not input_data.get('genre', False):
            abort(400)
        if not input_data.get('publish_year', False):
            abort(400)
        if not input_data.get('image', False):
            abort(400)
        if not input_data.get('current_book', False):
            abort(400)

        title_input = input_data.get('title')
        author_input = input_data.get('author')
        genre_input = input_data.get('genre')
        short_description_input = input_data.get('short_description')
        long_description_input = input_data.get('long_description')
        publish_year_input = input_data.get('publish_year')
        image_input = input_data.get('image')
        rating_input = input_data.get('rating')
        current_book_input = input_data.get('current_book')
        input_book = Book(title=title_input, author=author_input,
                          genre=genre_input, short_description=short_description_input,
                          long_description=long_description_input,
                          publish_year=publish_year_input, image=image_input,
                          rating=rating_input, current_book=current_book_input)
        db.session.add(input_book)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(Book.serialize(input_book))
```

and the postman POST request

```
[
 { 
        "title":"Here goes the title",
        "author":"Best author",
        "current_book":true,
        "genre": "Classic",
        "id": 1,
        "image": "pictures/bookpicture1.png",
        "long_description": "reaaaally good book)",
        "publish year": 1803,
        "rating": 3.5,
        "short_description": "read it!!"
    }
 ]
```

Comment: I'd assume it's `input_data`.  What's up with the trailing `]` on your request JSON?  Looks like part of a list.

Comment: @Samwise, I edited it now.  without the [] I get "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Comment: Look at the server logs for a more helpful error message?

Comment: File "/Users/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users//venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users//server/main.py", line 408, in books
    if not input_data.get('title', False):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Dont really now how to interpret the logs. Its obviously something with the " if not input_data.get('title', False)" line of code. But I dont know what could be wrong..

Comment: Based on that stack trace it still sounds like `input_data` is a list, and obviously your code is treating it as a dict, hence the error.  Maybe you should try printing it so you can look in the logs and see what it contains?  I'd also suggest putting the full stack trace and other useful info in your original question rather than just in the comments.